# Hadoop spring namespace not detected

Tags: java, spring, maven, hadoop, jar

I am creating a jar using Maven-jar plugin and on execution I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace 
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```

I am using Hadoop 1.2.1 version.

My applicationContext.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="hadoop.properties" />
......
</beans>
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>spring-hadoop-wordcount</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-hadoop-wordcount</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-hadoop-wordcount</name>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-streaming</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have added the jars to my src/main/resources folder.

I am unable to identify the problem. Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: it is not necessary to add jars to src/main/resources, maven will load them automatically from Internet. Try to build it using: mvn -U ...

Comment: I build it in eclipse using maven install and it does download automatically. But on jar execution it still says that it is unable to detect the hadoop even if I had added the dependencies like spring-hadoop-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an [AppendingTransformers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer) to your pom.xml.